# test the localhost in android emulator

Tags: android, struts, localhost

My web application runs in localhost server. In my emulator the URL is http://localhost:8080/myaction

Is it possible to retrieve the information from the server?

Comment: Please mark your preferred answer as correct (checkmark beside the answer) so that others may see at a glance which is the correct answer and the author gets the reward.

Answer (score 128):

Localhost is device's own loopback interface, if you're trying to access your development machine use 10.0.2.2.

More about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: thank u. and how to get the database connection from our web application. i want to retrieve the data from database i like listview in android pls help me

Comment: yeah... i'm not sure that the 10.0.2.2 is pointing to 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of 127.0.0.1 only. Hey, anyway, have you solved it @saravanan?