# Android cannot access localhost?

Tags: android, http, localhost

I started a local http server on Android and it can be reached by other computers in the same local network. But if I try to access this server using opera on the same phone, it won't work. So this means we are not able to access localhost on Android? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [test the localhost in android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234742/test-the-localhost-in-android-emulator)

Comment: Since I am using a device, it is not duplicated. I also tried 10.0.2.2 but still get nothing.

Comment: Why did you accept a **factually incorrect** answer which did not solve your problem???

Comment: Because my comment in that answer explains it was my fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shoud use next IP 10.0.2.2

Comment: I don't think so. I am using a real device, not emulator. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Btw, you may try start a http server using an app called kWS, and access it from the same phone browser. It always fails on my phone.

Comment: It was my fault! Opera on my device cannot access localhost, but the default browser can.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could not reach localhost from physical device, so only intercepting traffic via USB using adb helped:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77634616/8705119

Answer (score -1):

Just check this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

If ur app running in localhost:3000, then try to use as 10.0.2.2:3000 in your android emulator

Comment: No, this is not correct.  10.0.2.2 is for a server running on the machine hosting an emulator.  The server in this question runs on the device itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use your ip address in your pc (ipconfig to see the ip address for your pc)

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
```

So, use: `192.168.1.12:3000`