# error in connecting to local host in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android applicatiion in which i have to connect my app with local host.I have created an local host.I have made entries into database.Problem is that when i click on submit button its shows error in establishing connection/ connection refused,Has anyone done it before.Below is the code which i am firing on button click event .I have done R &d on this.and tried all methods.But could not find the solution

http://pastebin.com/Zq1JuVwW

Waiting for reply

Regards
Tushar

Comment: dont use locallhost, use like `http://10.0.2.2/`

Comment: try 10.0.0.2 instead of localhost

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android cannot access localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529784/android-cannot-access-localhost)

Comment: Also check this for detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234742/test-the-localhost-in-android-emulator/2235255#2235255

Comment: @nak,,,,, i have tried,,not working

Comment: just use your system's IP as like, "http://<192.168.1.#>/" and try to connect.

Comment: 10-13 12:59:54.485: ERROR/log_tag(411): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 0 of 
....Its giving this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use locallhost, use like `http://10.0.2.2/` kind of url. basically it is working for communicate with server

Comment: @nik,,,,, i have tried like u mentioned http://10.0.2.2/..but still connection refused,,

Comment: it is just example in my case i have use `http://213.109.115.53/MRES` but in your case its different