# Cannot browse site hosted on local machine from a mobile

Tags: android, http, localhost

I generated empty backbone application from [backbone-generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) on my OS X 10.9.1. Then changed the connect hostname in Gruntfile.js to '0.0.0.0' and start the app.

The issue is that I cannot access the application from Android connected to the same home wifi network. I know that my local machine ip is 192.168.1.101. So, I typed in a mobile browser 192.168.1.101:9000 but nothing is loaded.

I have found several similar questions on SO:

- [How to browse localhost on android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378501/how-to-browse-localhost-on-android-device)
- [Android cannot access localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529784/android-cannot-access-localhost)

But the answers did not help me and I cannot comment on them because of my low reputation.

Could anybody help with this issue and say what I'm missing?

Comment: did you consider turning off the firewall and shut down any anti virus in your PC?

Comment: the firewall is turned off and I have no antivirus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the issue reason was in the router wifi settings. The "WDS Settings" was disabled and to let devices communicate over network it should be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Questions that you reported deal with a local http server running on Android, in your case the application is running on your local machine, so it is necessary that your local machine and Android phone have IP addresses in the same subnet.

If you need to assign an IP_ADDRESS to your local machine (wi-fi interface), you can run in the Terminal

```
sudo ipconfig set en1 INFORM IP_ADDRESS
```

it may be useful for development purpose.

Comment: My local machine and android has 192.168.1.101/24 and 192.168.1.102/24 ips respectively. So, they are in the same subnet.

Comment: ok, sorry, but before I couldn't comment on your question.
Have you already tried to connect from another device? 
Running `lsof -Pan -i tcp -i udp`, could you check whether your server process is effectively listening on all interfaces there should be "TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)"? According to the gruntfile.js it should be ok, but it is better to check it also.
Moreover, you should check if in the Mac Firewall there is a rule that lets node.js to accept incoming connection.  http://www.macinstruct.com/node/165

Comment: The hosting configuration is correct. I can access the site when both my computer and phone in a corporate wireless network (10.10.2.0/24). But in my home local network I cannot do this. So, I think it may be a router issue