# WCF service on localhost that works in browser not working in PhoneGap

Tags: android, eclipse, wcf, web-services, cordova

Here is my web service that works perfectly fine in Fiddler and in my browser:
    http://localhost:11458/PlayerSvc.svc/GetPLayers

I then tried to call this via Jquery in phonegap and it failed:
here is my jquery in phonegap using Eclipse:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:11458/PlayerSvc.svc/GetPlayers',
            dataType: 'json',
           // timeout: 55000,
           // beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                //Possible to set any required headers here
                //xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'username password');
           // },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('failed');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
</script>
```

To make sure there was nothing wrong with my jquery I tested another webservice with this code and it was successful.   I am not sure how to gather more information on how to debug this. I tried wrapping my javascript with console.log(javascript above) and I could not get that to work. As you can see above I just used the alert function to output the failed error message. Any ideas? I think i may try using a try catch and then seeing if I can output the exception...

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator or a real device? for emulator see Kyberias answer. Otherwise use the network IP of your development machine on your network, probably in the 192.168.*.* range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running the PhoneGap application in the Android emulator? If yes, I think the localhost (127.0.0.1) in the emulator refers to the emulator itself and not the host machine. Perhaps you need to try another IP address (possibly 10.0.2.2 works).

Here's a question/answer that addresses this issue:

[test the localhost in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234742/test-the-localhost-in-android-emulator)

Comment: thanks you Very Much! that was the issue. I changed local host to 10.0.2.2 So http://10.0.2.2:11458/PlayerSvc.svc/GetPLayers and it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow whitelist urls and add your host address to external hosts in your phonegap.plist file.

http://geekaboo.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/ios5-whitelist-url-unauthorized-using-phonegap/

Comment: Well I am using Android and instead of the phonegap.plist file there is a phonegap.xml and i have added http://localhost:11458 to that file, so I don't think that is the problem.. Also strangely the test webservice that I was using the ensure that my javascript is not the issue worked even though i had not added it to the phonegap.xml file....